# django issues urls on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, cloud

Hello I am deploying an test project on heroku and I got this error

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named hello.urls
```

this is my Procfile file
    web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT

the project name is hello all run ok except the app when I run heroku ps give

```
Process  State       Command
-------  ----------  -----------------------------------
web.1    up for 29s  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.
```

Comment: did you resolve the issue? If so , how? I have the same one.

Comment: I'd like to say yes but no. I gave up with heroku :S , if you resolve please share the way!!! :)

Comment: I submitted a ticket to heroku support hopefully they help out. this is annoying. I sure will. I am curious what are you using currently?

Comment: I was doing the getting started tutorial in django using postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a python path issue. If you paste your project code somewhere, I'd be happy to take a look for you. I'd basically need to see:

- Site structure (folders, files).
- Your `settings.py` file.